# In App Purchases - Products Loaded Issue (RW Tutorial)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Developing my first app and unquantifiably grateful to this community for all the help.

My question is specifically related to Ray Wonderlich's In-App Purchases Tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases.

I do not appear to have the problem everyone else does with my SKproductsrequest method. I return the correct number of 5 objects for my response.counts when running on device and my KProductsLoadedNotification posts successfully.

I believe the issue is in my (void)productsloaded method which is as follows:

```
- (void)productsLoaded:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Products loaded called");
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    [self.ItemTable reloadData];

    NSLog(@"table reloaded");
}
```

As far as I can tell this method is never being called. My table simply never loads the products and timesout even with a very long delay. I don't know why as I have checked all my code back against the tutorial. When I run the tutorial sample project it is clear that this method should be running after SKproductsrequest but it just doesn't.

My best guess is that the issue is related to my use of storyboard's rather than Xib's. productsloaded is in my original view controller .m file. Could this be the problem? Any other ideas?

I am in Xcode 4.2 using storyboard and the project compiles with no errors.

Thank you so so much for any help you can provide. I really appreciate it.